# AWS ElasticSearch access denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-elasticsearch

when creating AWS Elasticsearch domain, i used IPv4 based access policy, I have tried using my public IP address or allow all IP address but still get access denied when I tried Kibana.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "es:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:es:us-west-2:xxxxxxx:domain/xxxxx/*",
      "Condition": {
        "IpAddress": {
          "aws:SourceIp": "*"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

or

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "es:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:es:us-west-2:xxxxxxx:domain/xxxxxx/*",
      "Condition": {
        "IpAddress": {
          "aws:SourceIp": "xx.xx.xx.xx/32"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

when I click `Kibana` link I always get error:

```
{
"Message": "User: anonymous is not authorized to perform: es:ESHttpGet"
}
```

any idea about the access policy configure?

Comment: Isn't this the same issue as described [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/anonymous-not-authorized-elasticsearch/)?

Comment: checked that one but still get the error

Comment: Do you use VPC for the ES domain?

Comment: I use public IP

Answer (score 0):

I don't think "aws:SourceIp" supports wildcard. For open access policy just remove the condition block:

[NOTE: This is not recommended as it will make your cluster open to world]

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "es:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:es:us-west-2:xxxxxxx:domain/xxxxx/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

The access policy should work when you just whitelist your particular IP. Maybe whitelist an EC2 instance public IP and then try to curl on your instance to make sure that there is no issue with your ES cluster.

```
curl <es-endpoint>

{
  "name" : "xxxx",
  "cluster_name" : "xxxx",
  "cluster_uuid" : "xxxx",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.2.0",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "tar",
    "build_hash" : "xxxx",
    "build_date" : "xxxx",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.0.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```